# ruby instantiating class using each

Tags: ruby

```
a = ["Select", "Choice", "Prime"]
a.each do |f|
    f.downcase = f.new
    f.grade = f
end
```

Is not a way to do this

```
select = Steak.new
select.grade = "Select"
choice = Steak.new
choice.grade = "Choice"
prime = Steak.new
prime.grade = "Prime"
```

Is it possible at all to instantiate several similar classes using each ?

Or another way ? It must be possible to do this more efficiently.

Comment: Where did you expect the `Steak` to come from?

Comment: Along with the answers provided you may be interested in parallel assignment in Ruby e.g. `a,b,c = [1,2,3]` then `a#=>1`, `b#=>2` and `c#=>3`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can:

```
grades = ["Select", "Choice", "Prime"]
steaks = []
grades.each do |grade|
  s = Steak.new
  s.grade = grade
  steaks << s
end
```

Comment: @BigRon when I was using `.map`, s would have been put into the resulting array automatically. I updated to use `.each` and am saving `s` explicitly. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks ! Doing that, I can access instances like this: `steaks[0].grade` which is not very clear, namely if I need to compare `steaks[0].grade < steaks[1].grade`. How can I give each instance a name , i.e. s is select, choice and prime. I tried `.map`, but then I would need an each in an each.

Answer (score 0):

OK, simple enough:

```
grades = ["Select", "Choice", "Prime"]
steaks = grades.map do |grade|
  steak = Steak.new
  steak.grade = grade.downcase
  steak
end
```

However, it really looks like the grade is an important characteristic of a Steak. Maybe it should be part of the constructor like this?

```
grades = ["Select", "Choice", "Prime"]
steaks = grades.map {|grade| Steak.new(grade.downcase) }
```

I presume that creating an initialize method can be left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I do this now :
`grades = ["Slect", "Choice", "Prime"]
names = grades.map{ |j| j.downcase }

names.zip(grades) { |r,n|
 r = Steak.new
 r.grade = n
 r.grade
  }`

Comment: @thiebo: that is... a weird thing to do. What did you mean to accomplish by using `.zip` like that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to name each instance (so use a hash instead of an array) you could do:

```
steaks = {}
["Select", "Choice", "Prime"].each do |grade|
    # I think using a symbol as key in this case is nicer
    steaks[grade.downcase.to_sym] = Steak.new(grade)
end
```

Or a bit shorter/optimal using map like you asked (support starting from ruby-2.1):

```
steaks = ["Select", "Choice", "Prime"].map{ |g| 
    [g.downcase.to_sym, new Steak(grade)] 
}.to_h
```

Another alternative would be to create a `Butcher` class which abstracts away all of this.

```
butcher = new Butcher.new
butcher.addNewSteak(Steak.new("Select"))
butcher.addNewSteak(Steak.new("Choice"))
butcher.addNewSteak(Steak.new("Prime"))

# Or added/created using a loop
["Select", "Choice", "Prime"].each do |grade|
    butcher.addNewSteak(Steak.new(grade)
end   

# Get a list of steaks
butcher.getAllSteaks()

# Get steak by grade 
bucher.getSteakByGrade("Select")

# Get all steaks by grade greater than
bucher.getSteakGradeGT("Choice")
```

Implementation of the Butcher class is left out intentionally. The elaboration is in response to the question posed under the answer of Alejandro C.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing what you are asking:

```
steaks = ["Select", "Choice", "Prime"].map do |grade|
  s = Steak.new
  s.grade = grade.downcase
  s
end
```

On the other hand, I recommend **against** having `grade` as mutable member. Mutability, leads to bugs. If `grade` is a fundamental part of `Steak` it should be initialized in the constructor:

```
class Steak
  def initialize(grade)
    @grade = grade.downcase
  end
end
```

Then your code would be simpler

```
steaks = ["Select", "Choice", "Prime"].map do |grade|
  Steak.new grade
end
```

Answer (score 0):

With this structure, you get a Hash with e.g. `:prime` as key and `Steak.new("Prime")` as value.
It makes it easier to iterate over all your steaks, and if you want a specific one, just use `steaks[:prime]` :

```
class Steak
  attr_reader :grade
  def initialize(grade)
    @grade = grade
  end

  def to_s
    format("Steak %s", grade)
  end
end

steaks = ["Select", "Choice", "Prime"].map{|grade| [grade.downcase.to_sym, Steak.new(grade)]}.to_h

p steaks
# {:select=>#<Steak:0x000000013e7000 @grade="Select">,
#  :choice=>#<Steak:0x000000013e6f60 @grade="Choice">,
#  :prime=>#<Steak:0x000000013e6ec0 @grade="Prime">}

puts steaks.values
# Steak Select
# Steak Choice
# Steak Prime

puts steaks[:select].grade # => "Select"
```

If you really want 3 separate variables for your steaks :

```
select, choice, prime = ["Select", "Choice", "Prime"].map{|grade| Steak.new(grade)}
```